# how to open another specific view controller in iPhone

Tags: ios

i am starter to iPhone programming. Maybe my question is too simple, but i can not understand the example that i found on the internet. I need your help.

I have lots of view controller on the storyboard.

And in some of these screens, i wrote the buttons programmatically . And now i want to go another screen when i push the button.

For example; i have two view controller that named HomeViewController and NotificationViewController. In HomeViewController, there is a button named "Notification Setting", when i push this button, program should open NotificationViewController.

How can it be written this code?

Thanks from now,

Answer (score -1):

first of all import your class and swrevealviewcontroller

```
#import "NotificationSettingsViewController.h"
#import <SWRevealViewController.h>
```

and than, the click method should be like this;

```
-(void)showNotificationSettings
{
NotificationSettingsViewController *myVC =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationSettingsViewController"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*) self.revealViewController.frontViewController;

[navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:NO];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

and finally go to storyboard and click your view, on right side of the page

click third tap , under identity field, there are two are named "Storyboard ID" and "Restoration ID". -Be sure your view must extend page's view controller-

Write your view controller name to "Storyboard ID" and check the "Use Storyboard ID".

In this situation, i wrote "NotificationSettingsViewController" .

That's all.